# why is onCommand never used in plugin

Tags: java, overriding, toggle, minecraft, bukkit

I'm creating a simple plugin for `Minecraft`, where it toggles a command and gets the target player a unique UUID. However the `public boolean onCommand` method states that it's never used.

**mainclass (Freeze.java)**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args){

    Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(!Freeze.toggleList.contains(player.getUniqueId())){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "sinut on jäädytetty tutkinnan ajaksi");
            Freeze.toggleList.add(player.getUniqueId());
        return true;
        } else if (Freeze.toggleList.contains(player.getUniqueId())){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED +"Et ole enään jäädytetty");
            Freeze.toggleList.remove(player.getUniqueId());
        return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have a specific class for what the command does

**(Toggle.java)**

```
public class Toggle implements Listener {
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent evt) {
    Player player = evt.getPlayer();
    if (Freeze.toggleList.contains(player.getUniqueId())){
        Location back = new Location(evt.getFrom().getWorld(), evt.getFrom().getX(), evt.getFrom().getY(), evt.getFrom().getZ());
        evt.getPlayer().teleport(back);
    }
}
```

}

Also in my `plugin.yml` I have the command for it:

```
    commands:
  freeze:
    usage: /<command>
    description: Freezez player.
```

Also the `@Override` is not working because "method does not override method from superclass".

Comment: If you change the method signature, its no longer an override, is it?

Comment: @Squiddie While your comment is short and to the point, you should post it as answer to get up-vote and answer points. Then again, with the OP being a (1-1), it may not see the light of day :) Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Squiddle I know what you mean. From my experience new OPs (i.e., they joined SO to ask a specific question) only have about a 30% probability of selecting an answer. But since you are replying anyways, putting it in an answer box rather than a comment box at least gives you the opportunity for points. Plus, those of us that value good SO answers, will up-vote.

Comment: onnipyivanen - For some reason someone down voted your question. It is a valid question and a problem that many new to Bukkit plugin development face; hence, I have upvoted it to counter the down vote. Also, please be kind to select @Squiddle 's post as the answer. While this may be the first and only time you post a question to SO, keep in mind that someone took the time to read and provide an answer to your question. Thank you in advanced for consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to register your command. This must be done so bukkit knows which object's `onCommand` method to call when the command is executed. To do this, use [command.setExecutor(CommandExecutor)](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/command/PluginCommand.html#setExecutor-org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor-)

```
javaplugin.getCommand("freeze").setExecutor(yourCommandExecutor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your IDE is telling you that your method is never used because it doesn't override the `onCommand` method in `JavaPlugin` (that's why you get the error "Method does not override method from its superclass").

This can have several reasons. Please check that

- Your main class is extending the `JavaPlugin` class in `org.bukkit.plugin.java`
- You imported the correct `Command` class. You need to import `org.bukkit.command.Command` and not `org.bukkit.material.Command`